# fls check and crud checking on generic

Tags: apex, pmd

I have AuraEnabled method in my class so lwc component can send an id of  sobject(could be any objects) and this method can delete it.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void deleteRecord(String recordId) {
    String objectName = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
    Schema.SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    String queryString = 'SELECT Id FROM ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectName) + ' WHERE Id IN :recordIds';
    List<SObject> records = Database.query(queryString);

    if(objectType.getDescribe().isDeletable()){
       delete record;//Warning on this line Validate CRUD.......
    }
}
```

However APEX PMD plugin in Visual Studio code complains Validate CRUD Permission Before SOQL/DML operation checking

Is there anything I can do about this or the plugin is just not working for all the cases like this?

Comment: I think you need to check for basic object read access before the database query is performed then this issue should disappear.

Comment: Are you doing this query to check to see if the user has sharing access to this record?

Comment: It could be just bug with apex pwd plugin select statement it doesn't really give me any warnings

Comment: Check this out:- [Apex PMD: Problem: Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233319/apex-pmd-problem-validate-crud-permission-before-soql-dml-operation)