# PMD check fails: validate CRUD before DML Operation

Tags: apex, pmd

I have a list of sObjects. In this list I have records of Account,Contact and Opportunity which needs to be updated. so before updating the list I am doing CRUD check on Account , Contact and Opportunity like below:

```
List<sObject> lstOfSObjects = new List<sObject>();
lstOfSObjects.add(new Account(.......));
...
lstOfSObjects.add(new Contact(.......));
...
lstOfSObjects.add(new Opportunity(.......));
...
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Account.isUpdateable()) {
 return...                   
}
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdateable()) {
 return...                   
}
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.isUpdateable()) {
  return...                
}

update lstOfSObjects;
```

Even if I am checking CRUD check for every sObject still Apex PMD is throwing an error at the update DML saying : Validate CRUD before DML Operation.

Any help?

Comment: These [answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233319/apex-pmd-problem-validate-crud-permission-before-soql-dml-operation) should help you out.

Comment: I think it's because you're using generic SObject list and not specific SObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMD either has a problem with a list of generic SObjects or it doesn't like the conditional blocks with early return statements.

This format may pass:

```
List<sObject> lstOfSObjects = new List<sObject>();
lstOfSObjects.add(new Account(.......));
...
lstOfSObjects.add(new Contact(.......));
...
lstOfSObjects.add(new Opportunity(.......));
...

if (Schema.sObjectType.Account.isUpdateable() && Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdateable() && Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.isUpdateable()) {
    update lstOfSObjects;
}
```

I know DML limits are a real concern, so if wrapping the DML call in an if-block still doesn't satisfy PMD you could also try making three lists of Accounts, Contacts, and Opportunities, and then finally use `List<SObject>.addAll()` to combine them together for the `update`.

Comment: Yea, the example that you shared, it worked.. Thank you so much..!!