# PMD rises `Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation`

Tags: apex, pmd

Let's say we have

```
       if(Schema.SObjectType.PermissionSetAssignment.isCreateable()){
            List<GroupMember> usersToInsert = new List<GroupMember>();
            for(AggregateResult usr : [SELECT assigneeId
                                        FROM PermissionSetAssignment
                                        WHERE ((PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = TRUE
                                                    AND PermissionSet.profile.name IN :profileNames)
                                                        OR PermissionSet.name IN :permissionSetNames)
                                                    AND assigneeId NOT IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId
                                                                            FROM GroupMember
                                                                            WHERE Group.Name = :groupName) 
                                        WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                                        GROUP BY assigneeId]){
                usersToInsert.add(new GroupMember(UserOrGroupId = (Id)usr.get('assigneeId'), GroupId = groupId));
            }
            insert usersToInsert;
        }
```

why we face PDM issue? is it possible to avoid it?
(Updated) it doesn't work if I even add WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED to SOQL query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apex PMD: Problem: Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233319/apex-pmd-problem-validate-crud-permission-before-soql-dml-operation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type you are inserting i.e. `GroupMember`:

```
if (Schema.SObjectType.GroupMember.isCreateable()){
    List<GroupMember> usersToInsert = new List<GroupMember>();
    ...
    insert usersToInsert;
}
```